# Windows Media Center HDMI Capture Cards

Tags: windows-media-center, hdmi, htpc, home-theater

I'm working on a new software application that utilizes windows media center to play recorded TV shows in the center of the screen.  We can get this to work with standard coax or RCA input TV Tuner/Capture cards.  My question is this...

Are there any TV tuner / capture cards out there that allow you to use Windows Media Center with an HDMI input of some kind?

#### UPDATE...

At the end of the day, all I truly need is for there to be some kind of system that will allow me to record a TV feed from a set top box via HDMI or Component Cables to a PC in order to playback that file inside of a WPF application.  Media Center recording isn't required...

Comment: the avermedia will do over the air (ota) capture but most cable stuff is probably hdcp by now thus avermedia's capture card probably won't support that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Hauppauge HD PVR](http://hauppauge.com/site/products/data_hdpvr.html) to record a component source. You can also use a [HDfury](http://www.hdfury.com/) to convert the HDMI source to component.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Avermedia AVerTV CaptureHD True HD 1080i.